# Question marks in headers for frameworks

Tags: xcode, parse-platform

All the frameworks have questions marks next to the headers in the project navigator. I committed the frameworks and had them modified but still there are question marks next to the headers. Does anyone know what I can do?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

That means that they have not been added to source control index even though they are a part of your project. When you go to commit in Xcode, you should see the same files with unchecked checkboxes next to them. Check those boxes to add them as part of your commit.

Comment: So I did that with the files but when i want to subclass the ParseUI framework to PFQueryViewController I'm not able to do it. The frameworks are added but not modified

Comment: @JoshEbrahimi you are asking a different question now. Your original question has to do with the symbols that Xcode's version control UI uses. Now you are asking a question specific to integrating and using Parse in a project. The two are not related and I suggest you open another question with the specific problem you are running into.

Comment: Ok then how do I remove the A symbols?

Comment: The 'A' symbols means that file has been added to your source control index. These will clear when you commit your changes. Sometimes Xcode's version control UI can get a bit wonky and not immediately recognize changes. In this case, if you see something you don't expect, I recommend using Xcode->Source Control->Refresh Status, or restart Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on framework name , and pop will show , in that pop up you have select add framework , then the question mark symbols will go away